# Merging Solr 3.4.0 indexes using lucene Merge Tool

Tags: lucene, solr

I have three solr 3.4.0 indexes that I want to merge, after searching I've found that there are two ways to do it:

1. Using Lucene Merge tool.
2. Merging through core admin

I am using lucene 3.4.0 and running following command:

```
java -cp d:/lucene/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar:./contrib/misc/lucene-misc-3.4.0.jarorg/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool ./newindex ./app1/solr/data/index ./app2/solr/data/index
```

but unfortunately it gives me following exception:

> Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>
> org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this particular problem by creating a new java application in net beans 7.1 and adding both the jar files as library. and inside my new application's main method i have called

IndexMergeTool.main

and pass all command line arguments to above mentioned method.

Regards
Ahsan

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things :-

```
./contrib/misc/lucene-misc-3.4.0.jar
```

Are you running it from the correct directory for it to find the jar. Why not use full path ?

You are using :(colon) as jar classpath separator, and using windows it should be ; (semi-colon)

Also - 
If you already have Solr running with the Solr indexes ready, I would recommend you to use the  second option - merging through Solr Admin.
This is more easy to use with direct http interface without any additional overheads and would work out of the box.

Comment: thanx for your valued response, I have tried that ur solution but now the error comes  as Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ./NewIndex

Comment: Why is it looking for NewIndex as a class. have a space between the jar and the class name e.g. java -cp d:/lucene/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar;./contrib/misc/lucene-misc-3.4.0.jar org/apache/lucene/misc/IndexMergeTool ./newindex ./app1/solr/data/index ./app2/solr/data/index

Comment: yeah i have given space between IndexMergeTool and ./newindex

Comment: without space same exception appears